# How to Display HTML Table Using Golang Template

Tags: go

I am trying to use html/template package to display a table of information in a web page in Golang. The current implementation of the template I have outputs to standard out.

I want to be able to pass the page content generated by the template to another function that will render my web page.

How to achieve this?

Explanation of code attached below. Basically, I want to capture the result of t.Execute(os.Stdout, persons) where persons is a slice of string. I know that t.Execute only returns an error. But it prints to standard out the template t along with the person name values. I wanted to capture the combined template and person array texts into a variable instead. I would like to assign the content to the body variable in my code below.

```
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`<table>{{range .}}<tr><td>{{.}}</td></tr>{{end}}</table>`))

    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, persons); err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
    title := "User Info Page"
    p := &Page{Title: title, Body: []byte(body)}
    renderTemplate(w, "view", p)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the template to a [bytes.Buffer](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer).  Use the contents of the buffer as the body.

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`<table>{{range .}}<tr><td>{{.}}</td></tr>{{end}}</table>`))

var body bytes.Buffer
if err := t.Execute(&body, persons); err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
title := "User Info Page"
p := &Page{Title: title, Body: body.Bytes()}
renderTemplate(w, "view", p)
```

If it's also a requirement to print to stdout, then add the following code after executing the template:

```
os.Stdout.Write(body.Bytes())
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems the right answer. I've looked at the Execute method in the documentation and it's expecting a Writer. I'll accept this.